# Start a sub-process (with sudo) as head of new process group, kill it after timeout, get the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, child-process

This is a bit of a tricky one ... I am writing a test suite for a Python project - running on Linux. As part of the tests, I have to fire up various commands (shell commands, small CLI tools, Perl scripts, etc). Some of those commands can hang or crash or loop forever and must be killed after a timeout.

A subset of those commands can also start an arbitrary number of sub-processes of their own, which must also be killed after the timeout (keywords: process groups and `setsid`). While the test suite runs with normal user privileges, some of the commands require super user privileges, i.e. `sudo`. If I have to use `sudo`, I sometimes need to preserve the original user's virtual environment, i.e. make it accessible for the super user.

Sometimes, I push my tests to a CI server, where `sudo` is not restricted / protected, but sometimes, I also want to test it on my local OS where `sudo` is password-protected. My test suite must therefore allow me to enter my super user password manually if required in a local test.

My (mostly working) solution is a routine named `run_command` (plus two helper routines named `__kill_proc__` and `__get_pid__`). So far, it looks like this:

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

import psutil # get it with "pip install psutil"


def run_command(cmd_list, return_output = False, sudo = False, sudo_env = False, timeout = None, setsid = False):

    cmd_prefix = []

    if sudo:
        cmd_prefix.append('sudo')
        if setsid:
            cmd_prefix.append('-b') # equivalent to "setsid", will spawn new process group including sudo
        if sudo_env: # preserve the user's virtual env for super user
            cmd_prefix.append('env')
            cmd_prefix.append('%s=%s' % ('VIRTUAL_ENV', os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV']))
            cmd_prefix.append('%s=%s:%s' % ('PATH', os.path.join(os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'], 'bin'), os.environ['PATH']))
    elif setsid:
        cmd_prefix.append('setsid') # TODO untested codepath

    full_cmd = cmd_prefix + cmd_list

    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        full_cmd, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE
        )

    timeout_alert = ''
    if timeout is not None:
        try:
            outs, errs = proc.communicate(timeout = timeout) # If command does not time out, this works just fine
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            timeout_alert = '\n\nCOMMAND TIMED OUT AND WAS KILLED!'
            if setsid:
                kill_pid = __get_pid__(full_cmd) # proc.pid will deliver wrong pid!
            else:
                kill_pid = proc.pid
            __kill_proc__(kill_pid, k_signal = signal.SIGINT, entire_group = setsid, sudo = sudo)
            outs, errs = (proc.stdout.read(), proc.stderr.read()) # PROBLEM: outs and errs are *always* empty! Buffer issue?
            # outs, errs = proc.communicate() # Makes no difference here, outs and errs are always empty this way, too.
    else:
        outs, errs = proc.communicate()

    if return_output:
        return (not bool(proc.returncode), outs.decode('utf-8'), errs.decode('utf-8') + timeout_alert)
    return not bool(proc.returncode)


def __kill_proc__(pid, k_signal = signal.SIGINT, entire_group = False, sudo = False):

    if not sudo:
        if entire_group:
            os.killpg(os.getpgid(pid), k_signal)
        else:
            os.kill(pid, k_signal)
    else:
        if entire_group:
            run_command(['kill', '-%d' % k_signal, '--', '-%d' % os.getpgid(pid)], sudo = sudo)
        else:
            run_command(['kill', '-%d' % k_signal, '%d' % pid], sudo = sudo)


def __get_pid__(cmd_line_list):

    for pid in psutil.pids():
        proc = psutil.Process(pid)
        if cmd_line_list == proc.cmdline():
            return proc.pid
    raise # TODO some error ...
```

The most troubling bit for me is when I have to start a new process group with `sudo` and it times out (I have discussed the current design of how I start a process group with `sudo` [here on SE Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411036/sudo-setsid-command-does-not-spawn-new-process-group)). It works, but it has a fundamental problem: If the sub-process (-group) times out and I kill it, I lose ALL output from this process group and I can not figure out what is going on. I commented the lines in question.

I understand that the above code is a really ugly collection of bad hacks ... I am seriously interested whether this is a good approach or not, how I could possibly improve it or how I should re-implement it.

(*I am wondering whether it is better to run the test suite altogether with super user privileges and reduce the privilege level for individual routines or sub-processes, which could cause a whole new set of problems.*)

Comment: Why did you name your functions `__function_name__`?

Comment: @MrGrj I have organized my testing infrastructure for this particular project into a module ('projectname_libtest'), which is imported by the actual test files (``test_*.py``, auto-discovered by ``pytest``). In this context, I want ensure that I do not import or use those "internal" helper routines by accident from/at another place ... Only ``run_command`` is intended to be "exposed".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34337840/cant-terminate-a-sudo-process-created-with-python-in-ubuntu-15-10